# When to use viewDidLoad and when to use awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I've gotten pretty comfortable using the viewDidLoad method to execute things I want done at the beginning of a view, but reading one of Apple's tutorials they set the data controller for the class in the awakeFromNib method and did nothing in the awakeFromNib. I swapped it and it seemingly worked identically in my app, but I'm not sure if it was better to have it in awakeFromNib or viewDidLoad.

When should I use either one?

Comment: In a Tab controller be ware of this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15786529/547341][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15786529/547341

Answer (score 9):

`awakeFromNib` is called when the associated nib file  with a class is loaded . Any class that can own a nib can use it. `viewDidLoad` is used only by view controllers. It is usually called when loading from nib as well but it can also be called by a view created in memory (very rare circumstance.). If you are using controllers, then I would suggest you to use `viewDidLoad`

For more Refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6455350/1887603)

Answer (score 2):

viewDidLoad is associated with the view controller. If you need to initialize another control unarchived from the nib (e.g. UITableViewCell prototype) you cannot overload viewDidLoad, you need to overload awakeFromNib.