# Objective-C iOS Development Using viewDidLoad or initWithCoder when setting Variables and Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, iboutlet, initwithcoder

So it seems like I should be setting my member variables in `viewDidLoad` - but I am confused as to why setting these variables in `initWithCoder` fails, since both are called at the start of the program.

In particular I have a line of code:

```
[worldView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
```

In which `worldView` is a `IBOutlet` `MKMapView` object. It works under `viewDidLoad`, but not `initWithCoder`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects do not yet exist when `initWithCoder` is called, and they do when `viewDidLoad` is called. Check your `initWithCoder` method by logging out the value of `worldView` using something like:

```
NSLog(@"World View: %@", worldView);
```

and it will be `nil`. They will be initialized before the call to `viewDidLoad`, so you can set a property of that `IBOutlet` there.

Comment: How come there are no errors when I put my code under initWithCoder (when worldView doesn't exist yet)? If worldView does not exist, shouldn't the compiler complain since I'm trying to set variables of a nil object?

Comment: @user3084415: Sending messages to nil is allowed in Objective-C (and is effectively ignored for methods that do not have a return value).

Answer (score 5):

The outlets are not yet connected when `initWithCoder` is called.
From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib):

> During the instantiation process, each object in the archive is
>   unarchived and then initialized with the method befitting its type.
>   Objects that conform to the `NSCoding` protocol (including all
>   subclasses of `UIView` and `UIViewController`) are initialized using their
>   `initWithCoder:` method.
>   ...
>   After all objects
>   have been instantiated and initialized, the nib-loading code
>   reestablishes the outlet and action connections for all of those
>   objects. It then calls the `awakeFromNib` method of the objects.

So  `awakeFromNib` would be a suitable place for the custom setup of your UI elements.

Comment: Also, asa a completion, if your variables are using the views frame, you should init them in `viewWillAppear` `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: It seems like my worldView object also does not exist in awakeFromNib. Is this expected?

Comment: @user3084415: No, I would all outlets to exist in awakeFromNib.

Comment: @MartinR Putting NSLog(@"World View: %@", worldView); under awakeFromNib reveals that worldView is a nil value for some reason... I don't know why.

Comment: @user3084415: What exactly do you load from the nib file? A view or a view controller?

Comment: @MartinR View controller I believe.

Comment: @user3084415: A view controller's *view* is loaded lazily, when it is accessed the first time. Then viewDidLoad is called.

Comment: Sorry - what difference would this make with awakeFromNib?

Comment: @user3084415: It seems that my answer does not really fit your problem. If you have a custom *view* class and the view is loaded from a nib file, then you can use awakeFromNib in the view class to setup UI elements. But you have a *view controller* loaded from a nib, and the view controller's view is loaded lazily, so viewDidLoad in the view controller class is the right place. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078708/when-to-use-viewdidload-and-when-to-use-awakefromnib. - So you might consider to accept Joel's answer instead, as he gave the correct answer first.